# sql Query Where optimization

Tags: oracle11g

I have written 2 quarries, which are

1) `Select c,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6... from table1 where Id is NULL;`

In table1 there are 10000's of records and column Id doesn't have null value. This query takes 5 min. to execute. And

2) `Select c,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6... from table1 where Id = 'abvccdhu9887687698';`

this query takes less than a second.

How this time difference is occurs

Please help me..I am waiting for your valuable suggestions

Comment: Have you created indexes in that table?

Comment: Yes, I have created Index on ID

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.il/2006/01/something-about-nothing.html) Tom Kyte post.

Basically, if the index you've created on ID column is a B-tree index then it will not index the records with `null` value in ID column.
So in query (1) it doesn't uses the index and in query (2) it does.

There is a workaround-
You can create an index on `(ID,0)` (not just on `(ID)`).